# Light contact tab melted into plastic housing

Tags: electrical

[image]

Hi there

I’ve been given an old floor lamp that I’d like to use, but it only works with one light bulb that I’ve tried and I need it to work with another.

Investigating the floor lamp, I can see that the contact tab has been pushed down and melted into the plastic housing. I’ve tried releasing it but it’s glued fast. I’m thinking that the best way to overcome this is to solder in a new copper contact tab onto the original, but I’m interested in receiving some advice as to whether this is the best approach. Any advice welcome.

Comment: If it were me, I'd replace the whole socket. You can find replacement lamp sockets in the electrical or lighting section of most hardware stores.

Comment: How hard would it be to simply disassemble it and replace it with a new lamp socket?  In most lamps I've encountered, it's easy to unscrew it, and a new lamp base is only a few dollars.

Comment: Good thinking jbeldock and Nate S. I’ll look into how easy it is to take apart.

Answer (score 4):

You don't solder something onto the center contact. Multiple reasons, one being it's already damaged form too much heat, another being the fact that a lamp socket should be UL rated, and that goes out the window when you modify it.

You buy a new lamp socket (at your local hardware store, or lacking one, online) and replace the whole socket. This will require some minor disassembly of the lamp, and you should carefully examine the cord to see if you should be replacing that as well due to old-age issues when replacing the socket.